# How to view *public only* interface of Swift file in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode there's a "Generated Interface" for swift files.  It shows public and internal items.  I want to see a swift file's `public` interface *only*.  No `internal`.  Is there a way view a public-only interface?

Comment: I have filed a bug for this with Apple years ago. Any century now!